# What is sample rate of DSO and what if we have a DSO with low value for sample rate?

Tags: electrical, dsp, hantek-dso5102p

I bought a USB DSO and its sample rate is only 48MS/Sec. I never had any problems measuring normal signals from a function generator and other circuits. I have seen many DSOs with high sample rate upto 1GS/Sec. What makes those different from mine and can anyone describe when my scope will get stuck due to low sample rate?

Answer (score 1):

> What makes those different from mine

They have a faster clock, a faster ADC, and faster processing to store the samples at a higher rate.

> when my scope will get stuck due to low sample rate.

From the [Nyquist theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), to reconstruct a signal with bandwidth \$\Delta f\$ in Hz requires sampling at \$2\Delta f\$ samples per second or higher.

So your scope won't be able to reconstruct signals at more than 24 MHz.

Practically, it probably has an anti-aliasing filter to limit the bandwidth to slightly below that (10 MHz? 16 MHz? 20 MHz?) and avoid issues that come when you try to reconstruct a signal just at the Nyquist limit.